# No power at outlets and lights, no bad breakers

Tags: receptacle

In the living dining room several outlets and two overhead lights are dead.

At the service panel I checked all the circuit breakers outputs for power, and all are live. I also checked every GFI circuit in the house I could find and tripped and reset them all. I still have no power on the aforementioned circuits.

I also loosened and tightened each breaker screw holding respective wires, both at the breaker switches and neutral wires.

Still no power.

Comment: Are the outlets in question wired using the side-screws or the backstabs?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Has this always been the case? If not, what else changed?

Answer (score 4):

Are all the outlets / lights on 1 circuit, If so find the last working device from the panel or the First non working device, I find back stabs are the cause for this type of problem in the high 90%. In this case the failed junction may be at a light switch where the outlet is also powered via a splice before the switch, the other possibility would be where a outlet feeds the switches. As I said at the start most times I find this problem it is from a failed back stabs in a 15 amp circuit. I have found both 15 & 20 amp circuits that have had a loose wire nut or a broken wire usually right at the point where the wire was stripped. These are the main failures I have found over many years with daisy chained circuits.